# Ordinary differential equation: $ y'=7\cos(x)+\cos(y) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \begin{cases}
y'=7\cos(x)+\cos(y)\\
y(0)=0
\end{cases} $$
in $ (-a,a) ,a>0$

given that $ \varphi(x) $ is a solution to the IVP, prove that $\varphi (x) $ is an odd function.

Using trigonometric identities I reached that $$\varphi ' (x)=6cos(x)+2\cos\left(\frac{x+\varphi(x)}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{x-\varphi(x)}{2}\right) $$
I don't think we were taught the tools to actually find the solution.
If I can prove that the derivative is an even function I should be good, any leads on how to get it though?

Comment: Perhaps show that $\psi(x) = -\varphi(-x)$ is also a solution, and by the uniqueness theorem it has to equal $\varphi(x)$? You shouldn't be needing any particular trigonometric identities for that, other than knowing the cosine is even.

Comment: Thank you very much!
because  $ \left(-\varphi(-x)\right)'=\varphi(-x) $
We get the equation system: 
$$ \begin{cases}
\varphi'(x)=\cos(7x)+\cos(\varphi(x))\\
-\varphi(-x)=\cos(7x)+\cos(-\varphi(-x))
\end{cases} $$
Subtracting the second row gives us in return:
$$ \varphi'(x)-\varphi'(-x)=\cos(\varphi(x))-\cos(-\varphi(-x))\Rightarrow \\
\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(-x)=\cos(\varphi(x))-\cos(\varphi(-x)) \\
\varphi'(x)-\cos(\varphi(x))=\varphi'(-x)-\cos(\varphi'(-x)) $$
Hence they are the same and they both equal $ \cos (7x) $ ?